# Prevent iPhone from charging when plugged into a battery powered MacBook Air

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, power, charge

I would like to prevent my iPhone draining power from my MacBook Air while the laptop is not plugged in and relying on battery power. How would I do this? Note, there doesn't seem to be any "unpowered USB ports" on the MacBook Air, both of them seem to charge my iPhone even when the laptop is not plugged into a power socket...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there is a software way to do that, but there is an hardware way:

1. Use an unpowered USB cable (some company makes it, targeting audiophiles), might need an adapter to male lightning.
2. Tape/Remove the power plugs on your USB cable.

Also, not exactly an answer to your question, but maybe to your use-case:
Build a binary, then export it to iTunes, then upload via wifi.
No debbuger and much less convenient tho.

Comment: Using an unpowered USB cable or blocking the power wires could result in damage to the device.

Comment: @g.rocket Blocking the power wires improperly might, but using an unpowered USB cable definitely would not.

Comment: The iPhone was never designed to be connected to USB without the power and ground attached, so it could damage the lightning interface (or possibly the entire device).

Comment: I don't know if this works on older devices with the 30-pin connector, but I tested it with a device with a Lightning connector and it doesn't work. The Lightning cable has electronics in it that need power from the USB host. The device won't connect.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the only other reason that you would connect your iPhone to your MacBook Air other than charging would be syncing. As far as I know there is no way to disable to charging aspect although you can work around it by syncing over WiFi rather than cable. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, there's another reason, to test apps you are developing.

Comment: Oh yeah, surprised I forgot that being a developer myself. Sorry about that.